# Junit assertion failures in Eclipse shown as stack trace rather than in Junit tab

Tags: eclipse, junit

Typically I've seen Junit Assert failures appear in the Junit tab, with a red bar.
However, Eclipse has not started showing all failures as a stack trace, like the below. How do I configure it to show them in the Junit tab?

Thanks

(some output messed up with gt lt symbols)

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: but was:
 at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:145)
 at org.mskcc.portal.oncoPrintSpecLanguage.OncoPrintSpecificationTestInParser.testOncoPrintSpecificationInParser(OncoPrintSpecificationTestInParser.java:507)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error `ComparisonFailure` is thrown from `Assert.assertEquals`, not your code. So I think it is already ALL stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The assert didn't fail, per se, the value you were comparing is actually a stack trace.   The assert is showing the expected and actual values.  The expected is blank. Is that supposed to be null or an empty string?

Maybe something like this happened:

```
//test code
String msg = foo.bar();
assertEquals(msg, "some string");

//code under test
class foo
{
    String bar()
    {
       try{return "some string";}
       catch (exception e)
       {
          return e.stacktrace(); 
       }
    }
}
```